HTMX pass parameter to hx-put (or hx-get) for searching one item and fill the edit form
How to pass id for search data using hx-put='http://localhost:0001/site/3', where 3 have been a dynamic value (it is a line in a grid). I use it with JavaSprngBoot on backend.
                  <tr th:each="model : ${models}">
                        <th scope="col">
                            <button type="button" title="Edit"
                                    class="btn btn-outline-primary"
                                    hx-put=/openai/model
                                    hx-vals=js:{"id":${model.getId()}}
                                    hx-target="body"
                                    hx-trigger="click">
                                <i class="bi-pencil"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" title="Delete"
                                    class="btn btn-outline-danger">
                                <i class="bi-trash"></i>
                            </button>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="row" th:text="${model.getId()}"></th>
                        <td th:text="${model.getModel()}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${model.getPrice()}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${model.getLimit()}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${model.getCreatedAt()}"></td>
                    </tr>

I need pass data from the edit-form, in ideal it works, when I pass data by hardcode - not dynamically. And ALL examples, which I seen later, was with hardcode values.So sad((

Why do you need to dynamically set the hx-put's value? Can you not just change your backend endpoint and pass the 3 as a parameter or in the put's body?
See: https://www.reddit.com/r/htmx/comments/18d45a3/comment/kcgbxvp/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button for dynamically changing values. You might have to call htmx.process()

This question is similar to: How to change hx-get value dynamically?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Another duplicate target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73658449/htmx-request-not-firing-when-hx-attributes-are-added-dynamically-from-javascrip?noredirect=1&lq=1

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I solved this problem: I added name="id" th:value="${model.getId()}" to my button, and it works for my case.
                  <tr th:each="model : ${models}">
                    <th scope="col">
                        <button type="button" title="Edit"
                                class="btn btn-outline-primary"
                                name="id" th:value="${model.getId()}"
                                hx-put=/openai/model
                                hx-target="body"
                                hx-trigger="click">
                            <i class="bi-pencil"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" title="Delete"
                                class="btn btn-outline-danger">
                            <i class="bi-trash"></i>
                        </button>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="row" th:text="${model.getId()}"></th>
                    <td th:text="${model.getModel()}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${model.getPrice()}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${model.getLimit()}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${model.getCreatedAt()}"></td>
                </tr>

All the suggested in a discussion answer options look useless without real code fragments, only with links to documentation, where the working answer itself is also not shown. The proposal, where suggested to change the endpoint on the backend, looks absurd, since the backend is sometimes developed separately from the client side, and teams may not have any connections at all.
HTMX - a technology that does not need JavaScript? However, it turns out that without JavaScript or adding a separate handler, we cannot solve such an elementary task as adding a value into an endpoint URL. Hmm..

But where are you using hx-put with the target you mention? It's not in your solution either?

You replaced the hx-vals with th:value, that seems to be the key thing here

Yes, after this changes hx-vals=js:{"id":${model.getId()}} is not needed

Yes, exuse me. I changed and endpoint too, I forget it. I removed from endpoint "/{id}" and added body of object, which will be changed in a form. So, I have to pass the "id" in another place, and I chose for it this button. Look, I added name="id" for this button and set value using th:value="${model.getId()}".
